# Hahn Banach Theorem extending distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

For any given distribution $T\in D'(\Omega)$, could $T$ has a coutinuous extension
$$\widetilde{T}:C_0(\Omega)\rightarrow R,\ \ \ \widetilde{T}\in(C_0(\Omega))'\ \ ?$$
Could you state a general version of Hahn Banach Theorem, in which we don't require $T$ to be a continuous linear functional of a **norm space**?

Comment: Hahn banach also holds in locally convex spaces. If it helps

Comment: Thank you. I have ever heard of this, but I can't find a rigorous statement and proof.

Comment: Look at the beginning of chapter 3 of Rudin's *Functional Analysis*.  3.6 there reads "If $f$ is a continuous linear functional on a subspace $M$ of a locally convex space $X$, then there exists $\Lambda\in X^*$ such that $\Lambda=f$ on $M$."

Comment: There is no reason you should have such an extension. Take, for instance, the derivative of the delta function as a counterexample.

Comment: There is such an extension if and only if $|Tf|\leq C \|f\|_\infty $ for all $f \in D (\Omega) $. Depending on your precise definition of $C_0 (\Omega) $, you don't even need Hahn-Banach. Density will suffice.